# pyqtSignal not updating QML in pyqt6

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml

The property in QML won't update even if I emitting a pyqtSignal().

I have this class:

```
class MainWindow(QObject):
    _instance = None

    window = None

    _auto_startup = False

    AutoStartupChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(MainWindow, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls._auto_startup = Configger.get_public("auto_startup") == "True"
        return cls._instance

    @pyqtProperty(bool, notify=AutoStartupChanged)
    def auto_startup(self):
        print("getting", self._auto_startup)
        return self._auto_startup

    @auto_startup.setter
    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def auto_startup(self, state):
        print("changing", self._auto_startup, state)
        self._auto_startup = state
        self.AutoStartupChanged.emit(state)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def toggle_auto_startup(self):
        from myproject import App

        print("toggling")

        App.toggle_auto_startup()
```

and in QML I have this snippet:

```
CheckBox {
      id: auto_startup_checkbox
      checked: main_window ? main_window.auto_startup : false
      onClicked: (!auto_startup_checkbox.updating && main_window) ? main_window.toggle_auto_startup(): null
      font.pointSize: 16
      Component.onCompleted: indicator.children[0].color = "green"
      text: qsTr("Auto startup")
    }
```

Everywhere I look I get this example and for everyone it solved their problems. For me the checkbox is not changing if I modify the `auto_startup` from another class like this `MainWindow().auto_startup = True`

When run this `MainWindow().auto_startup = True` the "changing" printed out and if I test the emitting event like this `self.AutoStartupChanged.connect(lambda state: print(state))` it printed out. However the "getting" function only runs when I load the qml file.

How to update the QML when I changing the variable?